# how to stop opening chromium browser while running the puppeteer scraping script?

Tags: chromium, puppeteer

I am using Puppeteer scrape a website. Everything is perfect except the script opens chromium browser everytime it runs. Can I stop that? Can I make it run in the background? It is not letting me to do anything because the opening chromim is having the control over all the open applications.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
async function main() {
  const productURL = `https://www.example.com`;
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setViewport({ width: 1020, height: 768 });
  const pageResponse = await page.goto(productURL, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0', timeout: 0 });
// scraping code based on selectors goes here....
  await browser.close();
}
```

Comment: Can you share some piece of your script?

Comment: Yes, I have added the code. How can I make the chromium not to open?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to enable headless mode:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true});
```

Headless mode is a browser mode for Chromium that doesn't open a window.

Comment: In this way, the website I am trying to scrape is giving 403 error.